# antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "path").permitAll() is still 401 unauthorized

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

I was searching a lot to find solution of my problem but nothing helps.

I am tryng to set up my Spring Security as:

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/shapes").hasAnyAuthority("USER")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/shapes").hasAnyAuthority("USER")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/shapes").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users", "/shapes/history").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable();
}
```

and now:

- every request on endpoint `/users` is open, is not secured
- `@PostMapping("/shapes")` is secured and returns 401 unauthorized
- `@GetMapping` is secured too - it returns 401 error if I not add username and password <- there is problem of that question
- `/shapes/history` is secured too

so the problem has to be here somewhere:

```java
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/shapes").hasAnyAuthority("USER")
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/shapes").hasAnyAuthority("USER")
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/shapes").permitAll()
```

I won't to change endpoints, I would like to have `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping` on the `/shapes`.

Comment: So you don’t want to secure any endpoint in your app?

Comment: What is the package of `HttpMethod`? What full URL do you call? What is your context root path?